# Applying one or more field level filtering on search results

Tags: lucene

How do I apply one or more field level filters on existing search results returned by `lucene`?

Thanks!
Ed

Answer (score 0):

Bluntly, looking at your [posting record](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41625/meyahoocomaodzxyowykprbavs5sf701zowgzpc3svjv8), you seem to be re-asking the same or very similar question repeatedly.

For general help in the area of Lucene and Information Retrieval, [Lucene in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394281) is excellent, and will provide you with a better grounding than the specific answers to specific questions you get here. Lucene also has excellent [online documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/) for whatever version you're using.